I was making an automated Excel and was using openpyxl in pyCharm i downloaded openpyxl then when i am adding the path its not accepting
import openpyxl
def load_data():
    path = r"C:\path\to\your\file\example.xlsx"

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.active

    list_values = list(sheet.values)
    print(list_values)


I am making all this using tkinter
I encountered an AttributeError when using openpyxl. It says module 'numpy' has no attribute 'short'. This happened while importing openpyxl in my Python script. Here is the traceback (sanitized for clarity):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\Ramaiah University\Programming Language\Python\imtermediate projects\Expense Tracker\main_Expense_Tracker.py", line 6, in <module>
    import openpyxl
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from openpyxl.compat.numbers import NUMPY
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\compat\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .numbers import NUMERIC_TYPES
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\compat\numbers.py", line 16, in <module>
    NUMERIC_TYPES = NUMERIC_TYPES + (numpy.short,
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'short'


Looks like you have a problem with your numpy installation. The Openpyxl version also may not be the latest release but shouldn't be the cause of the error. Tkinter seems to be completely irrelevant to the question.

Cannot reproduce the issue with latest openpyxl and numpy.  Do you have a file named numpy.py in your project folder?

do you mind sharing some more information?
Since you're using tkinter some other important code snippets could help.
I tried recreating your scenario and created a new project in pycharm with a python 3.13 venv.
The Version of the packages could also be helpfull.
Installed openpyxl with pip using "pip install openpyxl" and copied your code:
import openpyxl

def load_data():
    path = "F:\OneDrive\Desktop\example.xlsx"

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.active

    list_values = list(sheet.values)
    print(list_values)

load_data()

My output is:
F:\OneDrive\Coding\SO\venv\Scripts\python.exe F:\OneDrive\Coding\SO\main.py 
F:\OneDrive\Coding\SO\main.py:4: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\O'
path = "F:\OneDrive\Desktop\example.xlsx"
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (123, 456, 789, 0)]

Process finished with exit code 0

